# Ruby: Great GUI builder?

Tags: ruby, user-interface

I did some programming with Java and C# and they both have great GUI builders. Java has things like Netbeans and Eclipse, and C# has Visual Studio. It's pretty easy to build user interface with drag and drop. Lately I do some Ruby coding and I'm wondering if there is something similar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends from UI toolkit: for wxWidgets you can take DialogBlocks, for Qt — QtDesigner or QtCreator.

Answer (score 1):

You could always build it in [Glade](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?ruby-glade-create-template), or [SpecTcl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spectcl/), [VisualWx](http://visualwx.altervista.org/)

Komodo Edit used to have a SpecTcl integrated, but they didn't have time to improve it, so they [released it](http://community.activestate.com/faq/no-guibuilder-in-4-0) for others to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Java and C# come with their own User Interface Libraries out of the box, which Ruby doesn't have.  For Ruby, you'd need a third party library (which would likely be wrappings for Tcl or GTK).  Because there is no defined standardization there, there doesn't exist any powerful tools for building your interfaces in a graphical environment.

You can build it with tools such as [SpecTcl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spectcl/), which generates a Tcl interface with the appropriate Ruby bindings.  Alternatively, you could build your interface in a tool like [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups) to get the design down, and then manually write the code you need now that you have your X, Y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna throw one out there for [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/)

Comment: Please put some context on there - why are you throwing one out there?

Comment: Because it's a simple to use toolkit for building GUI apps with Ruby. It's even better if you're a beginner and a great way to build yourself up to something beefier. Also it's worth a try if for no other reason that it was created by _why.